# Google SQL Cloud timing out

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I can only guess that I'm missing something simple here.

I just started using Google Cloud MySQL.  Ran a number of transactions last week including importing a mysql dump, importing using Pentaho, and running some basic queries.  Seemed to be running well.

Today, I find that virtually nothing is working. Opening a table with ZERO records is taking 185 seconds.  Everything else is timing out.  IP address is fine.

Doing this through mysql workbench.

Is there some basic setting I'm missing here?  DB has 8 million records.  9 GB of my 250GB used.

Comment: Could you please contact support by sending an email to ` cloud-sql@google.com` including the name of your Cloud SQL instance?